# Salesforce Remote Access update fails

Tags: salesforce

When logged in as a standard user, an attempt to update a Salesforce field fails with the following:

HTTP response error code 400 (Bad Request).

The body of the response has:

{"message"=>"insufficient access rights on cross-reference id", "errorCode"=>"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS"}

Attempting the update with Admin privileges succeeds. So, are standard users not allowed to update records? Is there a role definition that allows update on records that the user has access to in the Salesforce application?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

standard users can update records that have edit rights to, check their profile settings, and make sure they have access to both the record you're trying to edit, and the record they are trying to reference.